# Bash PATH entries duplicated

Tags: linux, bash, path

I use fedora Linux, I manually installed .net core, java and add the path to the PATH

Today, I checked my PATH and the output below, as you can see, jdk, dotnet and gradle entries are all duplicated. can someone tell me how to get this resolved please

```
/opt/jdk/bin:/opt/jdk/bin:/home/xxx/.local/bin:/home/xxx/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/gradle/bin:/opt/dotnet:/opt/gradle/bin:/opt/dotnet
```

For readability:

```
/opt/jdk/bin:
/opt/jdk/bin:
/home/xxx/.local/bin:
/home/xxx/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/opt/gradle/bin:
/opt/dotnet:
/opt/gradle/bin:
/opt/dotnet
```

below are the entries I added to my .bashrc file

```sh
# Java path settings
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
# gradle building system
PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/bin

# Disable dotnet Telemetry
export DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
# Dotnet path settings
export DOTNET_ROOT=/opt/dotnet
PATH=$PATH:$DOTNET_ROOT

export PATH
```

The system part of setting files that modify the PATH are /etc/bashrc and /etc/profile, they both have below quoted code. is this caused the duplication? but when I read the comment, /etc/bashrc need to redo this becasue pathmunge is unset at the end of /etc/profile

```sh
    pathmunge () {
        case ":${PATH}:" in
            *:"$1":*)
                ;;
            *)
                if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                    PATH=$PATH:$1
                else
                    PATH=$1:$PATH
                fi
        esac
    }
```

Can someone help me out?
Thanks
B

Comment: We would have to know every script on your system that modifies your PATH variable, not possible.  But: go in `/etc` and do `grep -i path` to see if it is modified in there.  Then do the same thing in your user directory (.bashrc maybe?).  Somewhere in there the same code is done twice.

Comment: It's quite possible that JAVA added itself to a systemwide file if you used the installer.  Remove your manually added entry in `~/bashrc` , log out and back in and see if you still have duplicate entries.

Comment: Hi tink, I followed you advise to comment out the jdk path in ~/.bashrc, log out then log back in. all the jdk path got removed.

Comment: Hi Nic3500, I have added the code in the system setting files that modify the PATH variable.

Comment: shouldnt it be ``` PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin``` instead of ``` PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH``` ?

Comment: Hi Confused genius, I actually did some research, the order of this decides whether put jdk path in the beginning or at the end. it should duplicate the entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda live with it.

but I solved this by using the if, below is my solution

```sh
if ! [[ "$PATH" =~ "$JAVA_HOME/bin:/opt/gradle/bin:$DOTNET_ROOT:" ]] 
then
    PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:/opt/gradle/bin:$DOTNET_ROOT:$PATH"
fi
export PATH
```